# Array index out of bounds? How?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, sudoku, backtracking

Hello good people of stackoverflow!
I have a weird problem that I can't understand.
I'm gonna post my two methods that are problematic:

```
private static void resi(int [][] matrica,int row, int col) {
    if (matrica[row][col] != 0) {
        next(matrica,row, col); // <--- this the line that first throws the exception
    } else {
        for (int num = 1; num < 10; num++) {
            if (checkRow(matrica,row, num) && checkColumn(matrica,col, num) && checkBox(matrica,row, col, num)) {
                matrica2[row][col] = num;
                matrica4[row][col] = num;
                next(matrica,row, col);
            }
        }
        matrica[row][col] = 0;

    }
}
```

And the other one:

```
 private static void next(int [][] matrica2,int row, int col) {
    if (col < 8) {
        resi(matrica2,row, col + 1);
    } else {
        resi(matrica2,row + 1, 0);
    }
}
```

So, I'm making a sudoku solver based on some code I found online. 
Now, when I try to debug the program I can go over some of the lines nicely (and it works as expected) but once the program first reaches the call for "next" method in the method "resi" it crashes with array index out of bounds exception.
If I just try to run the program without debugging I get a lot of "array index out of bounds" exceptions in the output tab of NetBeans on the same method calls over and over again.

I don't know what's causing that error. As far as I can tell, row and col aren't exceeding the 0-8 range... It must be a problem with the 2D arrays?
Thank you for your time.

Edit 1:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9 
at SudokuGame.Main.resi(Main.java:88)
    at SudokuGame.Main.next(Main.java:107)
    at SudokuGame.Main.resi(Main.java:89)
    at SudokuGame.Main.next(Main.java:105)
    at SudokuGame.Main.resi(Main.java:95)
```

... and so on, they are repeating since it seems like it's going through the code and keeps throwing exceptions?

Comment: Can you show us the initialisation of the arrays?

Comment: can you also mark the exact line that has the exception. I think you can guarantee an almost instant solution if you do this. Cheers.

Comment: btw what is matrica2 and matrica4 in the resi-method?

Comment: paste the stracktrace

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: matrica2 and matrica4 are 2D arrays that are used to store the result of the sudoku puzzle. Keep in mind that int[][]matrica2 in the "next" method is local and I probably used a confusing name, so shame on me.

Comment: Tips:  1) Add @JohnnyAW (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify them* of a new comment. 2) Post an SSCCE.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Here's the example (which should be compilable). http://pastebin.com/REva5tby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `next()` you have been incrementing `row` but there is no fail-safe index out of bound check for `row` as there is for `col`, So there is not guarantee that`row` will exceed value greater than 8 i.e 9.

So, make sure to check if `row` is less than 8 or not before incrementing (`row+1`) in line `resi(matrica2,row + 1, 0);`.

```
private static void next(int [][] matrica2,int row, int col) {
if (col  8) {
    resi(matrica2,row, col + 1);
} else if(row < 8) { // Make sure to increment row only if less than 8
    resi(matrica2,row + 1, 0);
} else {
    // Stop the application (May Be)
 }
```

}

Comment: I think you might be up to something. I just noticed that I don't have a way of making the solver stop solving, which is, eventually, going to bring "row" above 8. I'm gonna try fixing it, and I'll post here.

Comment: Well, now the exceptions stopped happening. Which is good. But the program is running indefinitely now. I have written a line that should print out matrica4, but it never does. Again, when I try debugging it reaches the first "next" call and when I press F8 (step over) it no longer gives me an option to use F8, like it disables it because it's doing something that I can't interrupt.

Comment: Obviously, when all the rows and columns are done solving `next() method as in answer` don't do anything and thus the application goes in infinite loop. As I suggest you can put logic to stop application in `else block in next()` or try setting break point there. Also, it is better to close this question if you've solved the out of bound error.

Comment: It is to be noted that the application is recursive in nature and thus require a break point (a situation to get out of recursion). The probable break point is the `else block in next()`.

Comment: It says I should avoid comments saying "thanks", but I have to thank you for your help.

Comment: Accepting the answer or upvoting the answer is a way of saying thanks in StackOverflow. Hope, you've also fixed the problem with infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

The Execption will say exactly which line the problem occurs. Looking the code, I would guess that after some `next` calls, the third line of `resi` method (`next(matrica,row, col);`) will throw the execption due it miss some validation of the row. To we make sure, paste the execption on some site like pastebin.com and inform here to we see it =)